# Inno Setup, prompt for task based on results of script function

Tags: inno-setup

With Inno Setup, I have a task which I want to be conditional based on the results of a Pascal Script function.  If the function returns true, the task will be displayed and the user can either check or un-check it.  Otherwise, the task will not be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: mytask; Description: "My Task"; Check: IsTaskValid

[Code]

function IsTaskValid: Boolean;
begin
  Result := { Your decision logic };
end;
```